Polynomial maximizing its discriminant
Consider a polynomial $p(x) = (x-x_0)(x-x_1)\dots (x-x_{n-1})(x-x_n)$, with $-1 = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_{n-1} < x_n = 1$. What values for the roots $x_1, \dots x_{n-1}$ maximize the discriminant of $p$ or, equivalently, the absolute value of the Vandermonde determinant of the roots $x_i$ of $p$, i.e. $|\det V(x_0,\dots, x_n)| = |\prod_{0 \le i < j \le n} (x_i - x_j)|$?
It is clear that roots should be chosen symmetric to zero, so for $n$ even we have $x_{n/2} = 0$. For $n = 3,4$ this leads to polynomial optimization in one variable, which can be solved analytically, yielding
$$ n = 3 \rightarrow x_{1,2} = \mp \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}},\quad n = 4 \rightarrow x_{1,3} = \mp \sqrt{\frac{3}{7}}.$$
Beyond that the results of numerical optimization based on gradient descent revealed nothing particularly noteworthy.

And I also got $x_{1,2,3,4} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{7\pm 2\sqrt{7}}{21}}$ for $n=5.$

I think I have found a proof that $n(n+1)p(x)=p''(x)(x^2-1),$ I still have to work out the details. This would give us a simple method to obtain $p$ by equating coefficients. The roots would probably have to be determined numerically in most cases.

For $i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, the partial derivatives of $V(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ with respect to $x_i$ are the following
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i} V(x_0,\ldots,x_n)
=\pm
\prod_{\substack{j\neq i \\ k\neq i \\ j<k}} (x_k-x_j) \;
\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k\neq i}}^{n}
\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i \\ j\neq k}}^n (x_i-x_j)
$$
The first product is not $0$ and it does not depend on $x_i.$ Therefore, the necessary condition for getting a maximum of $V$ is
$$
\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k\neq i}}^{n}
\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i \\ j\neq k}}^n (x_i-x_j)
=0 \;\;\; \forall\; i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}
$$
Now we take a look at the second derivative of $p(x)$ with respect to $x.$ We get
$$
p'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq k}}^n (x-x_j)
$$
and
$$
p''(x) = \sum_{k_1=0}^{n}\sum_{\substack{k_2=0 \\ k_2\neq k_1}}^{n}
\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq k_1 \\ j\neq k_2 }}^n (x-x_j)
$$
Now we check what happens when we evaluate $p''$ at $x_i.$
The product in this expression avoids the factor $(x_j-x_j)$ only if $i=k_1$ or $i=k_2.$ Only one of $i=k_1$ and $i=k_2$ can be true at any given moment, because $k_1\neq k_2.$ We split the double sum into one part in which $k_1\neq i = k_2$ and one part in which $k_1 = i \neq k_2$ and we get the following
$$
p''(x_i) = 
\sum_{\substack{k_1=0 \\ k_1\neq i }}^{n}
\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq k_1 \\ j\neq i }}^n (x_i-x_j)
+
\sum_{\substack{k_2=0 \\ k_2\neq i }}^{n}
\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i \\ j\neq k_2 }}^n (x_i-x_j)
= 2
\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k\neq i }}^{n}
\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i \\ j\neq k }}^n (x_i-x_j)
$$
Setting this to $0$ is precisely the necessary condition for getting the maximum of $V.$
Therefore, the necessary condition can also be written as
$$
p''(x_i) = 0 \;\;\; \forall\; i\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}
$$
As the degree of $p''$ is two less than the degree of $p,$ we know that those are all roots of $p''.$ $p''$ cannot have any other roots. Therefore, $p''$ can be written as follows
$$
p''(x) = c(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\ldots (x-x_{n-1})
$$
with a suitable constant $c.$ We also know this constant, because we know the degree of $p.$ As this degree is $n+1$, the constant $c$ must be $n(n+1)$. So we have
\begin{eqnarray}
n(n+1)p(x) & = & c(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\ldots (x-x_n)  \\
& = & (x-x_0)(x-x_n)\;c(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\ldots (x-x_{n-1})  \\
& = & (x^2-1)p''(x)
\end{eqnarray}
We can now write $p$ in its expanded form as
$$
p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} a_kx^k
$$
and the second derivative is
$$
p''(x) = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} k(k-1)a_kx^{k-2}
$$
The coefficients can easily be found by using $n(n+1)p(x)=(x^2-1)p''(x)$ and sorting by the powers of $x.$ Note that the result of equating the coefficients is unique only up to a constant factor, this can be fixed by setting $a_{n+1}=1.$
Once we have $p$, we can find $x_1,\ldots x_{n-1}$ using numerical methods. I am not aware of an analytical approach to get the roots in general.
However, the maximum value of $V$ can be determined by using the resultant of $p$ and $p'$ without knowing the roots.

Very nice, thank you! If I see this right, this characterization leads to the Gegenbauer polynomials for $\alpha = -\frac{1}{2}$.
